# How to equally expand image buttons in Tkinter with grid weight approach?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to use tkinter to add squared buttons.

I know that default button size is with text (not pixel), thus I apply following tips to try to create square buttons:

1. Fix-ranged frame with `grid_propagate(False)`
2. grid `columnconfigure(x,weight=1)`
3. expand buttons by `sticky=W+E+S+N` .

The following case (button without image) is fine. All widths of three buttons are equally expanded to 100. Therefore all buttons are 100x100 square.

```
from tkinter import *

mainwin=Tk()
f = Frame(mainwin,width=300, height=100, bg = "black")
f.pack()
f.grid_propagate(False)

Bt1 = Button(f, bg = "#888888")
Bt1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W+E+S+N)
Bt2 = Button(f, bg = "#AAAAAA")
Bt2.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W+E+S+N)
Bt3 = Button(f, bg = "#CCCCCC")
Bt3.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=W+E+S+N)

f.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
f.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
f.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
f.columnconfigure(2,weight=1)

mainwin.mainloop()
```

[image]

But when I set image (50 pixel) on two buttons, all widths of three buttons are NOT equally expanded. Therefore all buttons are not square.

```
from tkinter import *

mainwin=Tk()
f = Frame(mainwin,width=300, height=100, bg = "black")
f.pack()
f.grid_propagate(False)

test_image = PhotoImage(file="test_50x50.png")

Bt1 = Button(f, bg = "#888888", compound='c')
Bt1["image"] = test_image
Bt1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W+E+S+N)
Bt2 = Button(f, bg = "#AAAAAA", compound='c')
Bt2["image"] = test_image
Bt2.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W+E+S+N)
Bt3 = Button(f, bg = "#CCCCCC", compound='c')
Bt3.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=W+E+S+N)

f.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
f.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
f.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
f.columnconfigure(2,weight=1)

mainwin.mainloop()
```

[image]

I GUESS that the "initial width" of all buttons will be calculated by (300-50*2)/3,
then the "final width" of buttons with image = initial width + its image width

In the above case final width = 115, 115, 70. For that 115-50(image size) = 65 is close to 70, the difference may be related to boundary or padding...

How could I equally expand image buttons to square-shaped with applying grid weight approach ?

Comment: Add `uniform=1` to all `f.columnconfigure(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Check This Out. I used a square of size: 50 by 50 pixels.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
mainwin=Tk()
f = Frame(mainwin,width=150, height=50, bg = "black")
f.pack()
f.grid_propagate(False)
image1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="D:/test/square.png")

Bt1 = Button(f, bg = "#888888",image=image1)
Bt1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+W+S+E)
Bt2 = Button(f,image=image1, bg = "#AAAAAA")
Bt2.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+W+S+E)
Bt3 = Button(f,image=image1, bg = "#CCCCCC")
Bt3.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=N+W+S+E)

f.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
f.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
f.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
f.columnconfigure(2,weight=1)

mainwin.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think the `Frame` width should be 300 instead of 150

Comment: I've tried PIL module, the result keeps the same.


( Your code behaves correctly because you apply image on "every button" AND  your frame width = image size(50)*3, your frame height = image size(50). Try my setting and you will find result keeps fail even if you use PIL)

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. That's why I had to reduce the width of the frame

Comment: Thanks for @Sujay 's trying, but the image size is indeed smaller than button in my project and I think it's no reason to modify image size to fill whole button.